# How to auto show dropdown of datalist?

Tags: angular

How would I go about getting the dropdown to show in this case when the data is fetched and filled inside of the `datalist`?

```
<input class="header-filter-search" (change)='onTaxpayerChosen($event)' [(ngModel)]="searchValue" placeholder=" Search accounts" type="text" (blur)="searchForUser()" [formControl]="query" list="accounts" id="account"/>
          <datalist id="accounts">
              <option *ngFor="let account of taxpayerList">{{account.name}}</option>
          </datalist>
```

I currently have to select a little arrow to show the dropdown once the options are filled but I cannot seen to find anything online that works with auto showing dropdowns of this format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `*ngIf="taxpayerList"` statement. It means that your `dataList` will not be rendered until `taxpayerList` will not be populated:

```
 <datalist id="productList">
   <select *ngIf="taxpayerList">
    <option *ngFor="let account of taxpayerList">
        {{account.name}} 
    </option>
   </select>
 </datalist>
```

UPDATE:

```
<p>Debug info: taxpayerList {{ taxpayerList | json }}</p>
<select>
    <option *ngFor="let account of taxpayerList" [value]="account.name"></option>
</select>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either, It's not a case of rendering it , more showing the dropdown when `taxpayerList` is populated. t the moment it's populated but not showing automatically.

Comment: Still no success @StepUp

Comment: @JvB please, see my updated answer. What do you see in `<p>Debug info: taxpayerList {{ taxpayerList | json }}</p>` ?

Comment: Ok, so for some reason your `select` and `ngif` additions randomly worked? No idea why though but thanks anyway! Really weird!

Answer (score 0):

```
      <datalist id="accounts" open>
          <option *ngFor="let account of taxpayerList">{{account.name}}</option>
      </datalist>
```

to show arrow

Comment: <span class="caret"></span>